# Custom amount of posts in category.php

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-post-type

I want to set a different amount of posts in my category.php. I want to display 15 articles per page with pagination.

I'm using the twenty-fourteent theme. How can I achieve this?

My code is:

```html
 
<?php
 
get_header(); ?>

 <section id="primary" class="content-area">
  <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
  
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
  

 ?>
  
   <div class="post-cat">
    
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
 the_post_thumbnail();
} 
?>
  <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p><?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></p>
 <?php endwhile; else : ?> 
  <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>

 
 <?php endif; ?>
  </div><!-- #content -->
 </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar( 'content' );
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is already nicely setup in twentyfourteen, so you don't need to modify anything with custom queries.

### Here is what you should do:

- Create a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) so that you can do modification in order that you don't loose any of your work on updates
- Use `pre_get_posts` to adjust the main query on your category page to show 15 posts per page.

Add the following to your child theme functions.php, or a custom plugin (*Please note, you need PHP 5.3+ installed for this to work due to the use of closures*)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query )
{
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_category() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 15 );
    }
});
```

Comment: Great answer, +1 for using `pre_get_posts`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
<?php

get_header(); ?>

    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

 <?php 

$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 15
));


 if ( have_posts() ) : while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); 


 ?>

        <div class="post-cat">

<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
    the_post_thumbnail();
} 
?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p><?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></p>
 <?php endwhile; else : ?> 
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>


 <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar( 'content' );
get_sidebar();
get_footer();


 ?>
```

Comment: As @user4717687 said, your solution will not work, your code will return the latest 15 posts regardless of category, so you have actually broken the category page functionality